# Validar campos dinamicos con FromRequest en laravel

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, laravel

**¿Como podria mostrar el error de de validación de cada campo dinamico que compone mi tabla.?**

Estoy utilizando un archivo fromrequest para validar cada campo de mi formulario, puedo observar los errores de aquellos campos que no son dinamicos como se puede ver en la imagen

[image: validaciones]

para aquellos campos que si son dinamicos directamente no muestra el error, es raro porque si lo estoy validando como campo requerido en mi archivo fromrequest.

este es mi archivo formrequest:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class SavePieceRequest extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        $rules = [             

            'denomination' => 'required',
            'code' => 'required',           
            'part_piece' => 'required',
            'number_gag' => 'required',          
            'number_program' => 'required',         
            'time' => 'required',         

        ];

        if($this->request->get('addmore')){
            foreach($this->request->get('addmore') as $key => $val)
            {
                $rules['position.'.$key] = 'required';
                $rules['code_tool.'.$key] = 'required';
                $rules['code_insert.'.$key] = 'required';
                $rules['quality.'.$key] = 'required';
            }
        }

        return $rules;

    }
}
```

Asi es como muestro los errores que poseen los campos de mi formulario, pero los campos que son dinamicos que agrego a traves de jquery y que tienen errores no los puedo visualizar.

```
$('#modal-btn-save').click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var form = $('#modal-body form'),
        url = form.attr('action'),
        method = $('input[name=_method]').val() == undefined ? 'POST' : 'PUT';        

    form.find('.help-block').remove();
    form.find('.form-group').removeClass('has-error');

    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        },
    });

    $.ajax({
        url : url,
        method: method,
        data : form.serialize(),
        success: function (response) { 
            form.trigger('reset');
            $('#modal').modal('hide');
            $('#datatable').DataTable().ajax.reload();       

            swal({
                type : 'success',
                title : '¡Éxito!',
                text : '¡Se han guardado los datos!'
            });
        },
        error : function (xhr) {
            var res = xhr.responseJSON;
            if ($.isEmptyObject(res) == false) {
                $.each(res.errors, function (key, value) {
                    $('#' + key)
                        .closest('.form-group')
                        .addClass('has-error')
                        .append('<span class="help-block"><strong>' + value + '</strong></span>');

                });
            }
        }
    })


});
```

**ACTUALIZADO 1**

Me he dado cuenta que necesito un (div class="form-group") por cada campo dinámico para mostrar el mensaje de error, porque asi lo requiere mi script,
asi es como mi script muestra el error de los campos que componen mi formulario:

```
 error : function (xhr) {
            var res = xhr.responseJSON;
            if ($.isEmptyObject(res) == false) {
                $.each(res.errors, function (key, value) {
                    $('#' + key)
                        .closest('.form-group')
                        .addClass('has-error')
                        .append('<span class="help-block"><strong>' + value + '</strong></span>');

                });
            }
```

pero aun asi no puedo visualizar el mensaje de error en mi formulario para los campos que son dinámicos, estoy intentando lo siguiente dentro de mi tabla dinamica:

Parte de mi formulariob (seccion heramientas)

```
                    <tbody>
                        @forelse ($piece->tools as $p)  
                        <tr> 

                            <input name="addmore[{{$loop->index}}][insert_id]" value="{{ $p->insert->id }}" hidden/>                       
                            <input name="addmore[{{$loop->index}}][tool_id]" value="{{ $p->id }}" hidden/> 
                            <td>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input type="text" name="addmore[{{$loop->index}}][position]" value="{{ $p->position }}" placeholder="Posición" class="form-control"/>
                                </div>
                            </td>
```

De la misma manera tengo un (div class="form-group") en mi script que me permite agregar el campo dinámico en este caso para el campo position

```
  $("#dynamicTable").append( 
        '<tr>' +           
            '<td>' +
                '<div class="form-group">' + 
                    '<input type="text" name="addmore['+i+'][position]" placeholder="Posicion" class="form-control"/>' +
                '</div>' + 
            '</td>' +
            '<td><input type="text" name="addmore['+i+'][code_tool]" placeholder="Herramienta" class="form-control" /></td>' +
```

Comment: Por favor ver mi actualizacion!

Answer (score 2):

Debes tener en cuenta que para la validación, Laravel funciona con la sintaxis de «punto», entonces, cuando anidas parámetros, utiliza el punto para dicho fin, en vez de los `[]` (aunque esto podría modificarse).

```
name="addmore['+i+'].position"
```

El índice sí se mantiene con corchetes, teniendo en cuenta que forma parte del primer parámetro.

En tu form Request, tu validación respectiva debe utilizar el * para los índices:

```
'addmore.*.position' => 'required',
```

Comment: gracias por comentar el la consola puedo ver que me indica el campo correspondiente que posee el error pero en mi formulario no puedo visualizarlo como si pasa con los demas campos, que puede suceder?

Comment: ¿Qué aparece en la consola?

Comment: ```{"message":"The given data was invalid.","errors":{"number_gag":["El campo number gag es obligatorio."],"addmore.2.position":["El campo addmore.2.position es obligatorio."],"addmore.2.code_tool":["El campo addmore.2.code_tool es obligatorio."]}}```

Comment: esos son los campos dinamicos en los cuales preciso que se indique el error correspondiente

Comment: Nunca he hecho este proceso solo con Bootstrap, siempre lo he aplicado con Vue y otras herramientas que me han facilitado el manejo de errores en campos dinámicos. Revisa un poco la documentación de Bootstrap, para que puedas adaptar los mensajes: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/forms/?#server-side

Comment: tendra que ver que todos mis campos en mi formulario estan declarados con laravelcollective por ejemplo: ```<div class="form-group col-md-4">                                        
                        {!! Form::label('denomination', 'Denominación') !!}                       
                        {!! Form::select('denomination', $denomination, null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'denomination', 'placeholder' => '']) !!}                              
                    </div>```

Comment: como paso este input de mi tabla dinamica a laravelcollective: ```<td>
                                <div class="form-group">                           
                                    <td><input type="text" name="addmore[{{$loop->index}}][position]" value="{{ $p->position }}" placeholder="Posición" class="form-control"/></td>
                                </div>
                            </td>```,  jstamente aca existen errores con laravelcollective: ```name="addmore[{{$loop->index}}][position]"```